Fault-tolerance of oscillator-to-oscillator codes
It was shown in arXiv:2102.05545 that oscillator-to-oscillator (O2O) codes do not exhibit a threshold, meaning there are no families of O2O codes that can convert physical displacement noise with variance below some threshold into logical noise with variance upper-bounded by any (arbitrary) constant. This result assumes encoding unitaries with a constant amount of squeezing and maximum likelihood error decoding.
Hence, O2O codes lack a fault-tolerance threshold in the conventional sense. Does this imply that O2O codes cannot be made fault-tolerant (under these conditions), or is there an alternative fault-tolerance criterion they could satisfy despite the absence of a threshold?
